# CSS - red font to Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have defined a class in my main.css file.

```
.red {
  color: #d14;
}
```

And using it like this.

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
       <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active red">
             <a href="/admin/list"><i class="icon-leaf icon-white"></i>Admin</a>
         </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Besides my main.css I also import the twitter bootstrap css file.

This way it does not work. Is it because Bootstrap is overruling my color definition?

Comment: If you want to style bootstrap entirely and not just one element have a look at this site: http://stylebootstrap.info/

Comment: @JohannesKlauß: Also here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html I'm not sure who made that other site, but it looks like they don't know how to use Twitter Bootstrap, their site is kind of messed up looking.

Comment: @WesleyMurch This works, but you don't have a live feedback on what you actually changed and how it looks compared to the other components, which stylebootstrap.info is capable of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only element in your markup that could visually apply this style is the `<a>`, and that element has a lot of really specific CSS rules applied to it by Twitter Bootstrap, stuff like this:

```
.navbar .nav .active > a,
.navbar .nav .active > a:hover {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

You'll have to write something even more specific to get the style to apply:

```
.navbar .navbar-inner .nav .red a {
  color: #d14;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pYGaG/

You *could* use `!important` on the rule if you really had to, but I really feel that you should avoid it as much as possible. If this is a single element that has this style, consider adding an `id` to it, which carries a lot of weight specificity-wise:

```
<li class="active" id="home_link">
   <a href="/admin/list"><i class="icon-leaf icon-white"></i>Admin</a>
</li>
```

```
#home_link a {
  color: #d14;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pYGaG/1/

Here are a couple good articles on CSS specificity:

- http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/
- http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

And as a side note, try to avoid presentational class names like `red`. Use more meaningful ones that aren't tied to the way it should look, but what it *is* (for example, `.active-link`).

Comment: Thanks! Great answer. Helped me to get more insight into how CSS works + and it works now.

Comment: TB has some really specific/far-reaching CSS selectors that are hard to override, in my experience so far with it, it's best to choose your battles wisely (or just use the CSS configurator or LESS to set up your own styles, and work with the framework instead of against it).

Answer (score 0):

Your're defining the red color on a `<li>`-Tag, but there is no text. The text is inside the `<a>`-Tag, so you need to overwrite this rule.

Code something like this:

```
.red a {
    color: #d14;
}
```

**Update:** Go for the answer given by Wesley Murch.